Updating NLog log path at runtime in ASP.NET MVC 5 application
I have a very simple task but for some reason not able to figure it out.
I have ASP.NET MVC 5 application that is using NLog. All NLog configuration is contained in nlog.config file - specifically logging path (as a variable).
Now I need to update logging path at runtime and I'm doing it like this (in Application_Start):
LogManager.Configuration.Variables["logDirectory"] = "C:/1111/111";
LogManager.ReconfigExistingLoggers();

But for some reason NLog is not picking up my change and still using path from nlog.config.
What am I doing wrong?

Make sure to use ${var:logDirectory} in your NLog configuration. See also https://github.com/NLog/NLog/wiki/Var-Layout-Renderer
